# How are Huffman trees transmitted?

Tags: compression, huffman-code, deflate

I'm trying to understand how the DEFLATE algorithm works. I found this [document published by UC Davis](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Emartel/122a/deflate.html). I don't understand the part where it talks about how Huffman trees are transmitted

> Probably the trickiest part of the DEFLATE specification to understand
> is the way trees are encoded to go along with the data, when that data
> is compressed with specialized trees.
>
> The trees are transmitted by their codelengths, as previously
> discussed. The codelengths are put all together into a sequence of
> numbers between 0 and 15 (the Huffman trees that are created must be
> kept to codelengths of no more than 15; this is the tricky part, not
> the part about constraining the order of the elements).
>
> Not all the elements have to be given codelengths; if the last
> elements of an alphabet are of 0 codelengths, they can and probably
> should be left out. The number of elements in each of the two
> alphabets will be transmitted, so the trimmed alphabets go together
> into a single sequence.

First of all, what does codelength mean exactly and why can it be 0?

Also I didn't understand run-length compression quite well, they mention it right after the last paragraph.

> Once this sequence of codelengths is assembled, it is compressed with
> a form of what is called run-length compression. When several elements
> in a row have the same codelength (often 0) special symbols may be
> used to indicate the number of elements with this codelength. Our
> sequence is now a sequence of numbers between 0 and 18 (possibly with
> extra bits forming integers to modify base values, as was the case
> with the length and distance codes).
>
> A Huffman tree is created for this alphabet of 0-18. Sigh. The
> sequence of 0-18 codes and extra bits is prepared with the Huffman
> codes replacing the 0-18 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A codelength is the length of the code in bits for that symbol.

A zero codelength means that that symbol does not appear in the compressed data, so there is no code for that symbol.

Run-length encoding means, in this case, that a sequence of repeated codelengths, e.g. "7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7", is replaced by "7, repeat the last length 5 times".

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest me a document to learn more about the deflate algorithm in detail, I didn't understand the one that I linked to in my question very well.

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1951